# Why is get_previous_post not returning null?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have simple script in Wordpress to get previous and next posts.
The only problem, is that the prevoius post (of the first post), doesn't return null, when there is no previous post.

The script is as follows:

```
$prevPost = get_previous_post();
echo $prevPost->ID;

$nextPost = get_next_post();
echo $nextPost->ID;
```

Now the problem is that, both variables gets the same value (the id for the next post). What should happen, is that $prevPost should return null, since there is no previous post!

Any suggestions?

Comment: plz provide your code for get_previous_post() so we can see

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow: The definition of get_previous_post() is located in http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L0.

Comment: This is strange as get_previous_post() returns empty if no previous post is there!

Comment: I have seen a couple with the same problem, but no solution.

Comment: Thanks @ChunLin. I am not the fan of Wordpress. Thanks for the Info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you could do something like this

```
$prevPost = get_previous_post();
$nextPost = get_next_post();

if($prevPost->ID === $nextpost->ID)
{
  echo 'No Previous Post';
  echo $nextPost->ID;
}
else
{
  echo $prevPost->ID;
  echo $nextPost->ID;
}
```

or just remove this line if need be

```
echo 'No Previous Post';
```

Comment: Not as elegant as i was hoping it would be, but looks like the only solution, since the native function is false :(.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can take a look at this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/ambrosite-nextprevious-post-link-plus/

It does provide the option to "Return false if no next/previous link is found, so themes may conditionally display alternate text."

Hope it helps.